# How to fix "member not found"- error in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
//html code for form
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="/action_page.php">
//submit button html code
<input type="button" id="submit" onclick="submit_form()" value="Submit">
//javascript submit function.
function submit_form()
{
document.getElementById("contactform").submit();
return false;
}
```

so here are the html and javascript snippets of my contact form, now when I am debugging my javascript code it is giving me a member not found error at the document.getElementById("contactform").submit(); line. The problem still persists even though the id of my button and the name of the function that runs are different. Can somebody please help me resolve this?

Comment: do you have this error on all browsers or any specific browsers?

Comment: None of the code you've posted so far would produce that error. Please update your question with a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

The problem was your input button had an ID of `submit`.

I renamed that id and you can see below a working code:

```js
function submit_form()
{
document.getElementById("contactform").submit()
return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="/action_page.php">

<input type="button" id="hsubmit" onclick="submit_form()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much! it works perfectly now. @Unamata Sanatarai

Comment: You could improve this answer by quoting from specifications (like the green box text on https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-form-element) that dictate that the form element gets dynamic attributes by the name or ID of its input controls.